# Selecting other columns not in count, group by

Tags: postgresql

So I have a table as follows

```
product_id      sender_id      timestamp      ...other columns...
1               2              1222
1               2              3423
1               2              1231
2               2              890
3               4              234
2               3              234234
```

I want to get rows where sender_id = 2, but I want to count and group by product_id and sort by timestamp descending. This means I need the following result

```
product_id      sender_id      timestamp      count      ...other columns...
1               2              3423           3
2               2              890            1
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT product_id, sender_id, timestamp, count(product_id), ...other columns...
FROM table
WHERE sender_id = 2
GROUP BY product_id
```

But I get the following error `Error in query: ERROR: column "table.sender_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Seems like I cannot SELECT columns that are not in the GROUP BY. Another method which I found online was to join

```
SELECT product_id, sender_id, timestamp, count, ...other columns...
FROM table
JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) AS count
    FROM table
    GROUP BY (product_id)
) table1 ON table.product_id = table1.product_id
WHERE sender_id = 2
GROUP BY product_id
```

But doing this simply lists all rows without grouping or counting. My guess is that the ON part simply extends table again.

Comment: `sender_id =2`  with  `product_id=1` have 3 different `timestamp`, so which one `timestamp` you need to choose for `order by` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze the latest one (largest one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping using `product_id, sender_id`

```
select product_id, sender_id, count(product_id), max(timestamp) maxtm 
from t
where sender_id = 2
group by product_id, sender_id
order by maxtm desc
```

If you want other columns too:

```
select t.*, t1.product_count
from t
inner join (
    select product_id, sender_id, count(product_id) product_count, max(timestamp) maxtm 
    from t
    where sender_id = 2
    group by product_id, sender_id
) t1
on t.product_id = t1.product_id and t.sender_id = t1.sender_id and t.timestamp = t1.maxtm
order by t1.maxtm desc
```

Comment: maked as correct but one question, what's the difference between keeping `where sender_id = 2` inside join, `t.sender_id = t1.sender_id` outside it and between ignoring these two and keeping `WHERE t.sender_id = 2` after the ON clause

Comment: @pewpewlasers - result should same, but performance (and execution plan) may be different,  don't know exactly,  needs testing and only notable with "big" tables. Also you can remove `where sender_id = 2` at all and since this is `INNER JOIN`, move that filter into `ON` clause, like: `on t.product_id = t1.product_id and t.timestamp = t1.maxtm and t.sender_id = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Just do a workout with your data:

```
CREATE TABLE products (product_id INTEGER,
sender_id INTEGER,
time_stamp INTEGER)

INSERT INTO products VALUES
(1,2,1222),
(1,2,3423),
(1,2,1231),
(2,2,890),
(3,4,234),
(2,3,234234)

SELECT  product_id,sender_id,string_agg(time_stamp::text,','),count(product_id) 
FROM products
WHERE sender_id=2
GROUP BY product_id,sender_id
```

Here you have distinct time_stamp ,so you need to apply some aggregate or just remove that column in select statement.

If you remove time_stamp in select statement then it would be very easy like below :

```
SELECT  product_id,sender_id,count(product_id) 
FROM products
WHERE sender_id=2
GROUP BY product_id,sender_id
```

Comment: works but still runs into an issue of returning other columns (if you have to return many columns for example)

Comment: You just put all the unique columns in group by clause which are in select statement  which dont have any aggregate operations.